# How do tokens give one cash?

Tags: transactions

I am completely new to the world of Stellar and wish to obtain some Tokens. I am looking to get some tokens that I can trade. I have read [this guide](https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/) guide on how to get tokens, but I am still in some confusion about how this relates to money.

I am confused to how you make money from the tokens. Once I have my tokens, what is the next step in trading them and gaining revenue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your newly created tokens on the [distributed exchange](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html): https://stellarterm.com/, where you can trade them for credits for any asset, such as USD or XLM.

Or, you can make up your own way to distribute them, such as a custom ICO (you will have to implement this yourself)